# How do some application by pass the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION even when they are using location service even when app killed?

Tags: android, geolocation, location

From the [android documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/background-location-access?hl=en), the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission should be stated for app that access the background location, user should see the "Allow all the time" option in the permission page of the application.

Yet, there are a lot of sports app, say strava, that track the gps of user continuously, even when app killed or app in background. They didn't even state the permission of ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION. This can be verify when going to their app permission page, only **allow only when using app**, **ask every time** and **refuse** options are shown. I understand they use foreground service to do such thing, but how come they didn't  state for the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission? Isn't this a must for apps to track user in background as required by Google?  Can anyone give me some explaination on this? Thanks

Comment: Depends on target version.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, can you give me more hints please? thanks